# Hadoop/Hive - Deducing Columns Into One based on CASE statements - Tough format

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have a data set that is shown like this:

[image: Current Data Set]

I'd like to get the data set to deduce down to one session per row, with a 'Yes' showing if it happened...so for instance, for session #5, it should show:

[image: Desired Data Set]

I'm using Hive to do this... Does anyone have any suggestions? Logically I can make sense on how to dot it, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

**Try below query you will definetly get the answer as expected above.**

select s_id,case when cont=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end,case when cont1=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end,case when cont2=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end,case when cont3=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end,case when cont4=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end,case when cont5=1 then 'Yes' else 'No' end from (select s_id,case when count(s_id)>1 or count(s_id)=1 then sum(cnt)  end as cont,case when count(s_id)>1 or count(s_id)=1 then sum(cnt1)  end as cont1,case when count(s_id)>1 or count(s_id)=1 then sum(cnt2)  end as cont2,case when count(s_id)>1 or count(s_id)=1 then sum(cnt3)  end as cont3,case when count(s_id)>1 or count(s_id)=1 then sum(cnt4)  end as cont4,case when count(s_id)>1 or count(s_id)=1 then sum(cnt5)  end as cont5 from (select s_id,case when dd=1 then 1 else 0 end as cnt,case when dd1=1 then 1 else 0 end as cnt1,case when dd2=1 then 1 else 0 end as cnt2,case when dd3=1 then 1 else 0 end as cnt3,case when dd4=1 then 1 else 0 end as cnt4,case when dd5=1 then 1 else 0 end as cnt5 from (select  s_id,regexp_replace(url1,'Yes',1) as dd,regexp_replace(url2,'Yes',1) as dd1,regexp_replace(url3,'Yes',1) as dd2,regexp_replace(url4,'Yes',1) as dd3,regexp_replace(url5,'Yes',1) as dd4,regexp_replace(url6,'Yes',1) as dd5 from eg4)a)b group by s_id)c;